# How to set position and size of Rebar control when used in client area?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2015

I am learning C++ and Winapi by creating a custom windows application; because I want to be able to give it my own look I got rid of non-client area and I am defining all border and title bar related actions myself. The control is working as intended in this test sample, but it always appears at the most top left corner of my window (which is whole client area only) and takes whole width of it (thus also covering my MIN / MAX / CLOSE buttons).

**How do I place Rebar menu into custom position in the client area using width I want and not automatically whole width of the window?**

I am subclassing Rebar control (in separate file) like so:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include "TitleMenu.h"

TitleMenu::TitleMenu ()
{
    /* Vars to take over params passed into class from main window */
    posX = NULL; // Position of control
    posY = NULL; // Position of control
    width = 0; // Width of control
    height = 0; // Height of control
    /* Control related variables */
    titleMenu = NULL; // Handle to control created as point of this class
    titleMenuToolbar = NULL; // Handle to control's toolbar
}

TitleMenu::~TitleMenu ()
{
    if ( titleMenu )
        DestroyWindow ( titleMenu );
}

TitleMenu* TitleMenu::CreateTitleMenu ( HWND hwnd, int posX, int posY, int width, int height )
// The purpose of this function is to create control and provide pointer to it; rebar control is used
{
    TitleMenu* p_titleMenu = new TitleMenu; // Control pointer

    p_titleMenu->titleMenu = CreateWindowEx ( 0, REBARCLASSNAME, 0, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, posX, posY, width, height, hwnd, 0, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong ( hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE ), p_titleMenu );
    if ( p_titleMenu->titleMenu == NULL )
    {
        delete p_titleMenu;
        MessageBox ( NULL, L"Problem creating the Menu.", L"Error", 0 );
        return 0;
    }

    p_titleMenu->titleMenuToolbar = CreateWindowEx ( 0, TOOLBARCLASSNAME, NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | TBSTYLE_FLAT | TBSTYLE_TRANSPARENT, posX, posY, width, height, p_titleMenu->titleMenu, 0, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong ( p_titleMenu->titleMenu, GWL_HINSTANCE ), NULL );
    if ( p_titleMenu->titleMenuToolbar == NULL )
    {
        MessageBox ( NULL, L"Error creating Menu toolbar.", L"Error", 0 );
    }

    /* Create test buttons for Rebar control */
    SendMessage ( p_titleMenu->titleMenuToolbar, TB_BUTTONSTRUCTSIZE, (WPARAM)sizeof ( TBBUTTON ), 0 );
        TBBUTTON tbb [ 3 ] =
    {
        { I_IMAGENONE, 0, TBSTATE_ENABLED, TBSTYLE_LIST },
        { I_IMAGENONE, 1, TBSTATE_ENABLED, TBSTYLE_LIST },
        { I_IMAGENONE, 2, TBSTATE_ENABLED, TBSTYLE_LIST },
    };
    SendMessage ( p_titleMenu->titleMenuToolbar, (UINT)TB_ADDBUTTONS, 3, (LPARAM)&tbb );

    /* Define band info */
    REBARBANDINFO rbBand;
    rbBand.cbSize = REBARBANDINFO_V3_SIZE;
    rbBand.fMask = RBBIM_STYLE | RBBIM_TEXT | RBBIM_CHILD | RBBIM_CHILDSIZE | RBBIM_SIZE | RBBIM_COLORS;
    rbBand.fStyle = RBBS_FIXEDSIZE | RBBS_HIDETITLE;

    // Get the height of the buttons to be used in toolbar
    DWORD dwBtnSize = (DWORD)SendMessage ( p_titleMenu->titleMenuToolbar, TB_GETBUTTONSIZE, 0, 0 );

    rbBand.cx = 300;
    rbBand.clrFore = RGB ( 233, 233, 233 );
    rbBand.clrBack = RGB ( 18, 18, 18 );
    rbBand.lpText = TEXT ( "" );
    rbBand.hwndChild = p_titleMenu->titleMenuToolbar;
    rbBand.cyChild = LOWORD ( dwBtnSize );
    rbBand.cyMinChild = LOWORD ( dwBtnSize );
    rbBand.cyMaxChild = LOWORD ( dwBtnSize );
    rbBand.cxMinChild = 3 * HIWORD ( dwBtnSize );
    rbBand.cyIntegral = 0;
    rbBand.cxIdeal = 300;
    SendMessage ( p_titleMenu->titleMenu, RB_INSERTBAND, (WPARAM)-1, (LPARAM)&rbBand );

    return p_titleMenu;
}
```

I am defining desirable width via `.cx` and using `RBBIM_SIZE` but that does not seem to have any effect.

I also tried sending `RB_SIZETORECT` like this without success:

```
RECT rc;
rc.top = 30;
rc.bottom = 60;
rc.left = 0;
rc.right = 300;
SendMessage ( p_titleMenu->titleMenu, RB_SIZETORECT, 0, (LPARAM)&rc );
```

Message `RB_SETBANDWIDTH` also gives no results (and from [MSDN describtion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774511(v=vs.85).aspx) I am not sure what to use as wParam argument).

```
SendMessage ( p_titleMenu->titleMenu, RB_SETBANDWIDTH, 0, 300 );
```

I could not find any other information related to this specific issue so I am asking here. Thank you!

Comment: The rebar sizes and positions itself automatically. One way you could control its position is to create it inside a child window (and then you position the child window). The child window would need to forward messages back and forth between the rebar and the parent.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Great idea, I will try that, thank you!